# Hibernate statement pool not working for db2 9.7 using C3P0

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="sessionFactory">

  <!-- Database connection settings -->

  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:db2://xx.xx.xx.xx:*****/DB</property>



  <property name="connection.username">XYZ</property>
  <property name="connection.password">XYZW</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>  
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1800</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3600</property>   
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>   
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</property>  
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">false</property>





 </session-factory>


</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is the Hibernate configuration file.
I am trying to use the prepared statement caching but with different parameters, getting cache miss and a new entry is getting added in the Global statement cache. I am using DB2 9.7 with JDBC 4.0 driver.

Answer (score 0):

Your pool can contain up to 200 Connections, and you've set a global max of 50 PreparedStatements. At capacity, your Connections will on average have 0.25 Statements cached, or more straightforwardly, 3 out of 4 Connections will not have any Statements cached. It's likely that your app uses many more than one PreparedStatement, so even those lucky few Connections with a Statement cached will mostly incur cache misses.

If you want fewer misses, set max_statements to something much higher, or better yet, eliminate the max_statements setting entirely and try the much easier to reason about `maxStatementsPerConnection` setting. Set that to something like the number pf PreparedStatements in frequent use in your application.

See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_statement_pooling for more information.